# android shared prefs backup: initial backup scheduled but not executed?

Tags: java, android, backup, preferences

I try to support shared prefs backup using BackupManagerService. The logs on the devices show that BackupManagerService detects after the app install that no backup exists and schedules the initial backup. However, it does not get executed. How long does it usually take to execute? What strings should I search for in the logs? Can someone please paste a log of a successful backup/initial backup?

I tried https://github.com/luciofm/BackupManagerTest but that does not work either. The onCreate method never gets called. Can someone please verify and fix the example?

Strangely, it works on an old android-10 Google sdk arm emulator image, but not on the corresponding x86 atom android-19 google sdk image, and not on my real devices (Samsung android-10 galaxy s-plus, samsung galaxy tablet 10.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the backup delay is quite large. After several hours, it finally did a backup run....